(Duplicate) Margins=True not summarizing well Pandas Pivot_Table
For the following code snippet and the result, since Margins=True gives the average of both values of a row, it calculates it wrong. Is there any explanation of it?
# Print the mean weekly_sales by department and type; fill missing values with 0s; sum all rows and cols
print(sales.pivot_table(values="weekly_sales", index="department", columns="type", fill_value=0,margins=True))
And the result is:
type                A           B        All
department                                  
1           30961.725   44050.627  32052.467
2           67600.159  112958.527  71380.023
3           17160.003   30580.655  18278.391
4           44285.399   51219.654  44863.254
5           34821.011   63236.875  37189.000
...               ...         ...        ...
96          21367.043    9528.538  20337.608
97          28471.267    5828.873  26584.401
98          12875.423     217.428  11820.590
99            379.124       0.000    379.124
All         23674.667   25696.678  23843.950

I searched whole the internet and found just a duplicate topic on this website.

It depends what need:
#sample data
print (sales)
   weekly_sales  department type
0             4           1    A
1             7           2    A
2             4           2    B
3             3           1    B
4             1           1    A
5             2           2    A
6             3           2    B
7             5           1    B

If check pandas.pivot_table:
margins bool, default False

If margins=True, special All columns and rows will be added with partial group aggregates across the categories on the rows and columns.

So output of columns depends of aggregation function:
Default aggregation - mean:
print(sales.pivot_table(values="weekly_sales", 
                        index="department", 
                        columns="type", 
                        fill_value=0,
                        margins=True))
type          A     B    All
department                  
1           2.5  4.00  3.250
2           4.5  3.50  4.000
All         3.5  3.75  3.625

Aggregation - mean (same output):
print(sales.pivot_table(values="weekly_sales", 
                        index="department",
                        columns="type",
                        aggfunc='mean', 
                        fill_value=0,
                        margins=True))
type          A     B    All
department                  
1           2.5  4.00  3.250
2           4.5  3.50  4.000
All         3.5  3.75  3.625

Aggregation - sum:
print(sales.pivot_table(values="weekly_sales", 
                        index="department", 
                        columns="type", 
                        aggfunc='sum', 
                        fill_value=0,
                        margins=True))
type         A   B  All
department             
1            5   8   13
2            9   7   16
All         14  15   29

Aggregation mean, All column/row filled by sum:
out = sales.pivot_table(values="weekly_sales", 
                        index="department", 
                        columns="type", 
                        aggfunc='mean', 
                        fill_value=0)
out['All'] = out.sum(axis=1)
out.loc['All'] = out.sum()
print (out)
type          A    B   All
department                
1           2.5  4.0   6.5
2           4.5  3.5   8.0
All         7.0  7.5  14.5

